# Why the compiler complains: the value of ‘testFunc’ is not usable in a constant expression？

Tags: c++, templates

Why the compiler complains:
the value of ‘testFunc’ is not usable in a constant expression.

But `reg(regHelper<&ctx::map_create>);`is ok. Why?

Here is the code snippest:

```
class ctx
{
    public:
        int map_create(void*){return 0;};
};


typedef int (ctx::*ctx_mem_func)(void*);

template <ctx_mem_func func>
int regHelper(void*) 
{
    return 0;
}

const ctx_mem_func testFunc = &ctx::map_create;

typedef int(*callBackFunc)(void*);

int reg(callBackFunc)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    reg(regHelper<testFunc>);
    //But this expression is ok.
    reg(regHelper<&ctx::map_create>);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Replace `const` by `constexpr`.

Comment: @molbdnilo The code snippet has been reedited.

Comment: @Jarod42 It does not work.

Comment: `testFunc` is not a compile-time constant. It's the same situation as `template<int i> void f(){}; int x = 1; void (*no)() = f<x>; void (*yes)() = f<1>;`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you. It has been revised now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [constant_expression#Usable_in_constant_expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Usable_in_constant_expressions)

> a variable is usable in constant expressions at a point P if
>
> - the variable is
>
>   - a constexpr variable, or
>   - it is a constant-initialized variable
>
>     - of reference type or
>     - of const-qualified integral or enumeration type

pointer on member doesn't have the "exception" of integral/enumeration types whereas `const` is sufficient.

You need to replace `const` by `constexpr`.

```
constexpr ctx_mem_func testFunc = &ctx::map_create;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c3a0ae5676a3c0f)

Comment: It's strange. The same code snippet complies ok on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/badf85416c3635d5 whereas the compiler complains on https://godbolt.org/z/KEfP5o(I met the same error message on Ubuntu).

Comment: After using -std=c++17, it compiles ok. But I don't know why it does not work when using c++11.

Comment: I would say, from [constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression), *"integral and enumeration (until C++17)non-type template arguments."*.

Answer (score 0):

Works because it's the proper syntax where regHelper is the reinterpret cast for ctx::map_create.

```
reg(regHelper<&ctx::map_create>);
```

Doesn't work because there are two functions calls here without a connection: luaCtx_mem_func testFunc:

```
constexpr luaCtx_mem_func testFunc = &luaCtx::map_create;
```

Comment: So, is it any possible way to make it work?